# Resharper colors settings missed in VS tools/options

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

I've missed all Resharper's colors options in VS tools/options/fonts & colors
(There is no entry started with "Resharper" word)

Is it the way to bring them back ?

Answer (score 1):

Solution found [HERE](http://www.jetbrains.net/devnet/message/5251797#5251797):

Please try clearing the HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\FontAndColors\Cache registry key.

**EDIT**:
Doesnt work for our boxes...