# Resharper - Missing Font & Colors settings option

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, resharper

I just installed newest version of ReSharper and now, I'm missing fonts and colors settings. I tried to do [this](https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206546479-ReSharper-Fonts-Colors-settings-do-not-appear-in-Visual-Studio-after-installation) but it doesn't work. Also i tried to clear registry like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846519/resharper-colors-settings-missed-in-vs-tools-options) but doesn't work too. Clean installation Visual Studio Community/Enterprise + ReSharper doesn`t help too. Any suggestions what can be wrong?

EDIT:

I did clean installation of visual studio 2015 community/enterprise (tried both). Then I installed resharper which is working but missing fonts and colors settings. I found solution - editing file C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio {VS version}\Common7\IDE‌​\Extensions\extension‌​s.configurationchange‌​d (typing anything there) but it doesn't work. I also tried to clear registry key HKEY_CURRENT_USER\So‌​ftware\Microsoft\Visu‌​alStudio\9.0\FontAndC‌​olors\Cache but it doesn't work too.

EDIT2:

Well I already resolved the problem - simply reboot PC helped me.

Comment: Hi Mathew, can you please include the steps you've taken in the question itself, rather than hidden by links?

Comment: Please click the edit link below your question and add it there, rather than as a comment :-)

Comment: Sorry I`m totally new here :). Done.